# How to sync a Drupal calendar with an iphone/ipad Calendar?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, datetime

Is there a way for us to sync our Drupal calendar to an iphone/ipad calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with https://www.drupal.org/project/date_ical you can create an ical feed display in views.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm very much willing to invest some time and learn how to use it but can you first confirm that sync can be done two-way? i.e any calendar entries entered into my iphone will be ported into my drupal site and any calendar entries entered into my drupal site will be ported into my iphone calendar?

Answer (score 2):

The [Date iCal](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_ical) module can be used for syncing a Drupal calendar in **both directions**. Some more details about it (from its project page):

> ... your one-stop shop for iCal support in Drupal. It provides a plugin for [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to enable exporting your site's calendar as an iCal feed, and a plugin for [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to enable importing external iCal feeds into your site's calendar.
>
> Any entity which contains a [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) field can be utilized by Date iCal for import and export of iCal feeds.

So it provides:

- a plugin for the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to enable **exporting** a Drupal calendar as an iCal feed.
- a plugin for the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module to enable **importing** external iCal feeds into a Drupal calendar.